# How to set border for fields in table?

Tags: html, css

I have table with some fields. I try to set border style only once:

```
md-grid-tile:not(.header), md-grid-tile:not(.md-grid-header) {
  border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

But I get border twice. I know there is trivial solution, but I forgot that

[image]

**HTML:**

```
 <md-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="10" id="alarm_schedule" class="md-grid-list-custom">

          <!-- Header -->
          <md-grid-tile rowspan="5" colspan="1" class="md-grid-header"><span>Урок</span></md-grid-tile>
          <md-grid-tile rowspan="5" colspan="1" class="md-grid-header"><span>Время (от)</span></md-grid-tile>
          <md-grid-tile rowspan="5" colspan="1" class="md-grid-header"><span>Время (до)</span></md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Comment: Post your HTML, too. We need a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's almost impossible to answer this question without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: I fixed question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making use of the [**`:first-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo-selector. Only applying a `border-left` to the first element causes the `border-right` for every element to **also** function as the left border.

You can use a `margin` of `-2px` to ensure that the cells have no gaps between them:

```css
md-grid-tile:not(.header),
md-grid-tile:not(.md-grid-header) {
  border-right: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: -2px;
}

md-grid-tile:first-of-type {
  border-left: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<md-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="10" id="alarm_schedule" class="md-grid-list-custom">
  <!-- Header -->
  <md-grid-tile rowspan="5" colspan="1" class="md-grid-header"><span>Урок</span></md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile rowspan="5" colspan="1" class="md-grid-header"><span>Время (от)</span></md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile rowspan="5" colspan="1" class="md-grid-header"><span>Время (до)</span></md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the rest of your CSS looks like, but you can assign a border-right and border-bottom to all cells, then apply a border-left to the `:first-child`

```css
md-grid-tile {
  float: left;
}

md-grid-tile:not(.header), md-grid-tile:not(.md-grid-header) {
  border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

md-grid-tile:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile-header>
    <h3>This is a header</h3>
  </md-grid-tile-header>
</md-grid-tile>

<md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile-header>
    <h3>This is a header</h3>
  </md-grid-tile-header>
</md-grid-tile>

<md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile-header>
    <h3>This is a header</h3>
  </md-grid-tile-header>
</md-grid-tile>
```